# Compiling with errors for .bib file in TeXStudio and TexMAker

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I'm new to Latex using it with TexMaker on Linux.

I tried to compile my .bib file, got some errors like missing the right fonts, then some .bst and .cls files that were missing and I added them manually. Now when I compile it seems to work only partially (my references are not fully integrated in the pdf file) and I have a message saying:

```
Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "bare_jrnl".tex
Could not start the command.
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

The font missing warnings still appear but it compiles.
One think to add  my .bib file has a different name from my .tex file. Tried to rename both the same but then everything crashed. Could this be the problem?

I recently tried to TeXstudio same problem... Can anyone advise?

Below the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.3.29) 8 NOV 2021 13:30
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**bare_jrnl.tex
(./bare_jrnl.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14> (./IEEEtran.cls
Document Class: IEEEtran 2015/08/26 V1.8b by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenA=\dimen134
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenB=\dimen135
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenC=\dimen136
\@IEEEtrantmpcountA=\count167
\@IEEEtrantmpcountB=\count168
\@IEEEtrantmpcountC=\count169
\@IEEEtrantmptoksA=\toks14
LaTeX Font Info: Trying to load font information for OT1+ptm on input line 5
03.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd
File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
)
-- Using 8.5in x 11in (letter) paper.
-- Using PDF output.
\@IEEEnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen137
-- This is a 10 point document.
\CLASSINFOnormalsizebaselineskip=\dimen138
\CLASSINFOnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen139
\IEEEnormaljot=\dimen140
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <5> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <5> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <7> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <7> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <8> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <8> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <9> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <9> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <10> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <11> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <11> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <12> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <12> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <17> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <17> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <20> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <20> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <24> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <24> not available
(Font) Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
\IEEEquantizedlength=\dimen141
\IEEEquantizedlengthdiff=\dimen142
\IEEEquantizedtextheightdiff=\dimen143
\IEEEilabelindentA=\dimen144
\IEEEilabelindentB=\dimen145
\IEEEilabelindent=\dimen146
\IEEEelabelindent=\dimen147
\IEEEdlabelindent=\dimen148
\IEEElabelindent=\dimen149
\IEEEiednormlabelsep=\dimen150
\IEEEiedmathlabelsep=\dimen151
\IEEEiedtopsep=\skip47
\c@section=\count170
\c@subsection=\count171
\c@subsubsection=\count172
\c@paragraph=\count173
\c@IEEEsubequation=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\c@figure=\count175
\c@table=\count176
\@IEEEeqnnumcols=\count177
\@IEEEeqncolcnt=\count178
\@IEEEsubeqnnumrollback=\count179
\@IEEEquantizeheightA=\dimen152
\@IEEEquantizeheightB=\dimen153
\@IEEEquantizeheightC=\dimen154
\@IEEEquantizeprevdepth=\dimen155
\@IEEEquantizemultiple=\count180
\@IEEEquantizeboxA=\box45
\@IEEEtmpitemindent=\dimen156
\IEEEPARstartletwidth=\dimen157
\c@IEEEbiography=\count181
\@IEEEtranrubishbin=\box46
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cite/cite.sty
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 302.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nocite on input line 332.
Package: cite 2015/02/27 v 5.5
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen158
\Gin@req@width=\dimen159
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2019/08/31 v2.4l Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen160
\ar@mcellbox=\box47
\extrarowheight=\dimen161
\NC@list=\toks16
\extratabsurround=\skip50
\backup@length=\skip51
\ar@cellbox=\box48
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-02-03 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count182
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box49
)
(build/bare_jrnl.aux)
\openout1 = `bare_jrnl.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 350.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 350.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 350.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 350.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 350.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 350.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 350.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 350.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 350.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 350.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 350.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 350.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 350.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 350.
-- Lines per column: 58 (exact).
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count183
\scratchdimen=\dimen162
\scratchbox=\box50
\nofMPsegments=\count184
\nofMParguments=\count185
\everyMPshowfont=\toks17
\MPscratchCnt=\count186
\MPscratchDim=\dimen163
\MPnumerator=\count187
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count188
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks18
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <9> on input line 438.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <6> on input line 438.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <5> on input line 438.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <7> on input line 481.
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
]
<../impro-hrp/figures/1_K_456.jpeg, id=11, 180.675pt x 281.05pt>
File: ../impro-hrp/figures/1_K_456.jpeg Graphic file (type jpg)
<use ../impro-hrp/figures/1_K_456.jpeg>
Package pdftex.def Info: ../impro-hrp/figures/1_K_456.jpeg used on input line
526.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 252.0pt x 392.00493pt.
[2 <../impro-hrp/figures/1_K_456.jpeg>]
<../impro-hrp/figures/2_heart_robot.jpeg, id=15, 276.03125pt x 183.68625pt>
File: ../impro-hrp/figures/2_heart_robot.jpeg Graphic file (type jpg)
<use ../impro-hrp/figures/2_heart_robot.jpeg>
Package pdftex.def Info: ../impro-hrp/figures/2_heart_robot.jpeg used on input
line 537.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 252.0pt x 167.70128pt.
[3 <../impro-hrp/figures/2_heart_robot.jpeg>]
<../impro-hrp/figures/2_sans_objet.jpg, id=19, 772.8875pt x 433.62pt>
File: ../impro-hrp/figures/2_sans_objet.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)
<use ../impro-hrp/figures/2_sans_objet.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: ../impro-hrp/figures/2_sans_objet.jpg used on input l
ine 561.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 252.0pt x 141.38136pt.
[4 <../impro-hrp/figures/2_sans_objet.jpg>]
<../impro-hrp/figures/3_rinaldo.jpg, id=23, 670.6656pt x 445.1832pt>
File: ../impro-hrp/figures/3_rinaldo.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)
<use ../impro-hrp/figures/3_rinaldo.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: ../impro-hrp/figures/3_rinaldo.jpg used on input line
577.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 252.0pt x 167.27614pt.
<../impro-hrp/figures/3_kob.jpg, id=24, 1204.5pt x 802.49812pt>
File: ../impro-hrp/figures/3_kob.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)
<use ../impro-hrp/figures/3_kob.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: ../impro-hrp/figures/3_kob.jpg used on input line 592
.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 252.0pt x 167.89282pt.
[5 <../impro-hrp/figures/3_rinaldo.jpg>] [6 <../impro-hrp/figures/3_kob.jpg>]
<../impro-hrp/figures/3_blind_robot.jpeg, id=31, 319.1925pt x 159.59625pt>
File: ../impro-hrp/figures/3_blind_robot.jpeg Graphic file (type jpg)
<use ../impro-hrp/figures/3_blind_robot.jpeg>
Package pdftex.def Info: ../impro-hrp/figures/3_blind_robot.jpeg used on input
line 607.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 252.0pt x 125.99927pt.
[7 <../impro-hrp/figures/3_blind_robot.jpeg>]
(build/bare_jrnl.bbl) [8] [9
] (build/bare_jrnl.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
2195 strings out of 483140
37250 string characters out of 5965151
281265 words of memory out of 5000000
17220 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
572834 words of font info for 88 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
39 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
30i,8n,28p,2831b,211s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r
.enc}</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb></
usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmb8a.pfb></usr/share/texli
ve/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmbi8a.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/
fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw
/times/utmri8a.pfb>
Output written on build/bare_jrnl.pdf (9 pages, 3889570 bytes).
PDF statistics:
61 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
38 compressed objects within 1 object stream
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
31 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Only the **first** error is relevant, check the .log file and copy the complete error into your question!

Comment: Thank you @Mensch here is the log message:

Comment: According to the log file a pdf with 9 pages is produced (6th line from the bottom). Also the log doesn't contain any errors, only some warnings about fonts which you should address at some point but these do not cause the error "Could not start the command" that you got from TeXmaker. So, according to the log things are ok. It doesn't mention anything about the bibliography though. Did you use any `\cite` commands in your document, and a `\bibliographystyle{}` and `\bibliography{}` command at the end? You tagged `biblatex` but you mention `.bst` files which indicates `bibtex` [...]

Comment: [...] and not `biblatex`, which of the two do you use/want to use/does TeXmaker think you want to use?

Comment: Thank you @Marijn, yes I do use "\cite" ,  \"bibliographystyle{{ieeetran}}" and "\bibliography{} " commands but at one point i got an error saying ieeetran.bst file was missing so I added it manually to my git folder. where can I find more insight about "bibtext" I think for  TexMaker is bibtex as I saw it in the comments of my .tex file ?

Comment: For information on bibtex vs. biblatex see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib. For your specific question it would help if you add the code of your document. You can remove unnecessary parts as long as the problem is still reproducible (i.e., at least one `\cite` command), also include the relevant entry from the `.bib` file. As a guess: after running `pdflatex` you also need to run `bibtex` and then `pdflatex` again for the references to actually show up. You can configure TeXmaker to do that automatically.

Comment: I added some photos with the settings and an example for \cite, not sure where i find the entry for the .bib file

Comment: In your screenshot there are 18 references shown in the pdf output, is that correct? If yes, how many are missing? Could you give an example of an entry that is not shown? You can open the `.bib` file in TeXmaker (or anywhere else, for example in gEdit) and locate the entry by the key (for example the `jenkins2009is` entry would start by `@article{jenkins2009is,` or `@inproceedings{jenkins2009is,` or `@book{jenkins2009is,` etc. depending on which type of publication it is).

Comment: yes, i have 3 ref not appearing (like @INPROCEEDINGS{hoffman2010ieee,

  author={Hoffman, Guy and Weinberg, Gil},

  booktitle={2010 IEEE International Conference on Robotics and Automation}, 

  title={Gesture-based human-robot Jazz improvisation}, 

  volume={},

  number={},

  pages={582-587},
  
  year={2010},

  doi={10.1109/ROBOT.2010.5509182}}
 it's an author i cite several times with different papers)

Comment: + 4 where the bibtex format is not respected (displaying page numbers after the year of edition in the pdf. reference section) @inproceedings{vorn2018alborg,
  title={Becoming cyborg: interdisciplinary approaches for exoskeleton research},
  author={Jochum, Elizabeth and Demers, Louis-Philippe and Vorn, Bill and Vlachos, Evgenios and McIlvenny, Paul and Raudaskoski, Pirkko},
  booktitle={Proceedings of EVA Copenhagen 2018: Politics of the machines-Art and after (Electronic Workshops in Computing)},
  pages={1-9},
  year={2018},
  organization={BCS Learning and Development Ltd.}
}

Comment: I see the Hoffman and Weinberg reference in your screenshot, it is nr. [8]. What exactly is the problem with this reference?

Comment: yes, nr. [8] is different from nr. [10] for example. in my bib file, for the citations the year is the last parameter and it does not seem to compile like that for some of them

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand what you mean. You said there are references not appearing, and `hoffman2010ieee` is one of them, but that reference _is_ appearing, so I wonder why you use that as an example. Also [8] is different from [10] because they are different references, right? Why do you expect them to be _not_ different? For the position of page numbers: BibTeX automatically formats the fields according to the style, and the actual order in the .bib file does not matter. For example, you can put the author last in the .bib file entry, or in the middle, but it will always appear

Comment: first in the reference list. In order to answer your question/clarify your situation it would be best if you would add the actual full text of the `.bib` file for the entries that are problematic, as real text (so not as image), and a small version of your document, with the documentclass and preamble but without any actual content, again as text and not as image. Then describe the output that you get and the output that you expect to get. In this way we can hopefully explain if there is indeed something wrong or if the output that you get is actually expected/normal (and why).